# CKEditor 5 customize mentions output with custom text and remove the marker

Tags: ckeditor5

I followed the example for generating "custom output" found in the CKEditor [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html#customizing-the-output) but all I can seem to get it to do is change the element type.  Continuing with the example I am trying to get the end result to be that the 'link' value gets inserted into the editor (not as a hyperlink, but as just plain text) and that the marker '@' gets removed.

So typing @ would bring up:

[image]

And selecting 'Barney Stinson' would insert the url as text like this:
[image]

Is this possible?  Does anyone have any examples they could point me to?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

here is example

[enter link description here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html)

look at
function customItemRenderer( item )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. URLs can go stale over time, so it's often helpful to copy some relevant text into your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use two fields for each FeedItem. The first is `ID` which is used by the plugin and must contain the marker as the first character. The second, and most important, is `Text` where you will indicate what the value of the mention displayed in the editor.

[Here it is an example (which follows the instructions provided by the documentation you already mentioned in your question)](https://gist.github.com/gianmarcosanti/abef1deaf36bff80a1d7cd0503811005)